# Zonal Statistics of a polygon and assigning mean value to the polygon

Tags: raster, gdal, zonal-statistics, python-3

I have a large shapefile filled with polygons, and a raster of that same area. I need to use Zonal statistics to find the mean value of the area under each polygon and then assign that value to the polygon.

What would be the best way to assign the mean values to their corresponding polygons for later retrieval?

I am working in Python, and using mainly GDAL/OGR.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 6):

There is a zonal statistics example in the [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook 1.0 documentation](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html#calculate-zonal-statistics).

> This recipe calculates statistics on values of a raster within the
>   zones of a vector dataset. It returns for each feature a dictionary
>   item (FID) with the statistical values in the following order:
>   Average, Mean, Medain, Standard Deviation, Variance

Although this is a viable option, the documentation recommends using the [rasterstats](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats) module.

---

```
import gdal, ogr, osr, numpy
import sys


def zonal_stats(feat, input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster):

    # Open data
    raster = gdal.Open(input_value_raster)
    shp = ogr.Open(input_zone_polygon)
    lyr = shp.GetLayer()

    # Get raster georeference info
    transform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    xOrigin = transform[0]
    yOrigin = transform[3]
    pixelWidth = transform[1]
    pixelHeight = transform[5]

    # Reproject vector geometry to same projection as raster
    sourceSR = lyr.GetSpatialRef()
    targetSR = osr.SpatialReference()
    targetSR.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    coordTrans = osr.CoordinateTransformation(sourceSR,targetSR)
    feat = lyr.GetNextFeature()
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    geom.Transform(coordTrans)

    # Get extent of feat
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    if (geom.GetGeometryName() == 'MULTIPOLYGON'):
        count = 0
        pointsX = []; pointsY = []
        for polygon in geom:
            geomInner = geom.GetGeometryRef(count)
            ring = geomInner.GetGeometryRef(0)
            numpoints = ring.GetPointCount()
            for p in range(numpoints):
                    lon, lat, z = ring.GetPoint(p)
                    pointsX.append(lon)
                    pointsY.append(lat)
            count += 1
    elif (geom.GetGeometryName() == 'POLYGON'):
        ring = geom.GetGeometryRef(0)
        numpoints = ring.GetPointCount()
        pointsX = []; pointsY = []
        for p in range(numpoints):
                lon, lat, z = ring.GetPoint(p)
                pointsX.append(lon)
                pointsY.append(lat)

    else:
        sys.exit("ERROR: Geometry needs to be either Polygon or Multipolygon")

    xmin = min(pointsX)
    xmax = max(pointsX)
    ymin = min(pointsY)
    ymax = max(pointsY)

    # Specify offset and rows and columns to read
    xoff = int((xmin - xOrigin)/pixelWidth)
    yoff = int((yOrigin - ymax)/pixelWidth)
    xcount = int((xmax - xmin)/pixelWidth)+1
    ycount = int((ymax - ymin)/pixelWidth)+1

    # Create memory target raster
    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('MEM').Create('', xcount, ycount, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((
        xmin, pixelWidth, 0,
        ymax, 0, pixelHeight,
    ))

    # Create for target raster the same projection as for the value raster
    raster_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
    raster_srs.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    target_ds.SetProjection(raster_srs.ExportToWkt())

    # Rasterize zone polygon to raster
    gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], lyr, burn_values=[1])

    # Read raster as arrays
    banddataraster = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    dataraster = banddataraster.ReadAsArray(xoff, yoff, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)

    bandmask = target_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    datamask = bandmask.ReadAsArray(0, 0, xcount, ycount).astype(numpy.float)

    # Mask zone of raster
    zoneraster = numpy.ma.masked_array(dataraster,  numpy.logical_not(datamask))

    # Calculate statistics of zonal raster
    return numpy.average(zoneraster),numpy.mean(zoneraster),numpy.median(zoneraster),numpy.std(zoneraster),numpy.var(zoneraster)


def loop_zonal_stats(input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster):

    shp = ogr.Open(input_zone_polygon)
    lyr = shp.GetLayer()
    featList = range(lyr.GetFeatureCount())
    statDict = {}

    for FID in featList:
        feat = lyr.GetFeature(FID)
        meanValue = zonal_stats(feat, input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster)
        statDict[FID] = meanValue
    return statDict

def main(input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster):
    return loop_zonal_stats(input_zone_polygon, input_value_raster)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    #
    # Returns for each feature a dictionary item (FID) with the statistical values in the following order: Average, Mean, Medain, Standard Deviation, Variance
    #
    # example run : $ python grid.py <full-path><output-shapefile-name>.shp xmin xmax ymin ymax gridHeight gridWidth
    #

    if len( sys.argv ) != 3:
        print "[ ERROR ] you must supply two arguments: input-zone-shapefile-name.shp input-value-raster-name.tif "
        sys.exit( 1 )
    print 'Returns for each feature a dictionary item (FID) with the statistical values in the following order: Average, Mean, Medain, Standard Deviation, Variance'
    print main( sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2] )
```

Comment: I've tried using the rasterstats module, but it breaks my python3 install due to a missing dependency for fiona. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get fiona for python3 installed. (Running OpenSUSE).

If I could get the zonal stats worked out, how would you go about assigning the mean value to a polygon?

Comment: Why not run Python 2.7*, perhaps in a virtual environment? Have you tried the GDAL example provided?

Comment: I'm trying it now. I'm having issues with getting the geotransforms for the raster, but that's on another thread. The image provided to me by my employer was already configured to Python 3. My main question right now is, once I get the zonal stats working, how/can you assign numerical values to a polygon?
I feel like this might be a really simple thing I'm missing.

Comment: I would recommend starting a follow-up thread.